Python-can delay in receiving data
I'm new to python-can and I have the following code to receive can messages and write it a csv file, but I'm facing delays in data getting updated when I print it to console:
import can
import logging
import pandas as pd

def _get_message(msg):
    return msg

class PCANBus(object):
    def __init__(self):

        logging.info("Initializing CANbus")
        
        self.bus = can.interface.Bus(interface='vector', app_name='EA7B', channel='0,1', receive_own_messages=True)
        self.buffer = can.BufferedReader()
        self.notifier = can.Notifier(self.bus, [_get_message, self.buffer])

    
    def read_input(self):      
        return self.buffer.get_message()

    def cleanup(self):
        self.notifier.stop()
        self.bus.shutdown()
           
pcan = PCANBus() 
fileName = "c:\\Data\\Can.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(fileName)
try:
    while True: 
        msg = pcan.read_input()
            
        if msg.arbitration_id == 780: #IDAS_30C
            print("Message value", msg)
            df.loc[df['Name']=="ADAS_CAM_EGO_LANE_HI_ACCU_POSX", ['value']] = str(msg.data[3] >> 1) 
                   
        try:   
            #sleep(0.5)
            #print("df to csv")
            df.to_csv(fileName, index=False)
        except PermissionError:
            print("File could not be opened")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
        
        #file.close()
        print("Program Exited")
        #df.to_csv("recorded.csv", index=False)  
        pcan.cleanup()


I checked the hardware and it is getting values immediately. But my code is seeing updates after 3-5sec.

How do you know it is taking 3 to 5 seconds to read your data?

It is just an estimate time when I update the signal value and see it through the print statement in the code. I'm using VN1610 hardware.

Try updating the print statement to force a flush print("Message value", msg, flush=flush)

Sure, I can do that. But I want to write the updated data to the CSV file as per the above code and there is a delay in the updated value there too.

Your code is currently writing to harddisk every time a message is received. You even write to disk when a message is received, which you do not store in df, i.e. when the message does not have id 700. This will for sure have a huge impact on the processing time.

I removed df.to_csv and it works fine. But I have to write it to csv file with each message, is there a way to do that?
